# Python Selenium Dropdown Menu Select

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

To click the "County" drop-down menu on this [page](https://reports.blm.gov/report/LR2000/23/Pub-MC-Geo-Index) I use this XPath with Selenium :

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="masterCustomDropDown"]/img')[3].click()
```

Since sometimes it will not error out nor actually perform the click action, I usually check if the elements in the drop-down menu are visible to see if the click function performed. Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`Select()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

```
//Create a new select element
Select choose = new Select(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="masterCustomDropDown"]/img'))

//Select the element at the 3rd index in the Select element we have reference to
choose.selectByIndex(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the **County** drop-down menu you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://reports.blm.gov/report/LR2000/23/Pub-MC-Geo-Index")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"dispReport")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@title='County']//following::img[1]"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Country]

Comment: I don't have a problem clicking it. I was asking if there is any way to verify the clicking action had been performed?